# Python Jupyter Notebook why does the Graph not Print inside a function?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

Why does the following code  not show me the Graph? When I try to print a Graph outside of a defined function the Graph is printed but inside a defined function the Graph does not print.

```
mat = [[TOP]]
from graphviz import Graph
def printMat(mat):
    graph = Graph()
    retList = []
    for i in mat: 
        if type(i) == EVENT: 
            return []
    else:
        for j in i:
            #print(j.name)
            graph.node(j.name)
            for k in j.nodes:
                graph.node(k.name)
                graph.edge(j.name, k.name)
                printMat(k.nodes)
                print(k.name)
     
   graph
```

Comment: You need to return the graph from the function.

Comment: @AKX Thanks but the Graph is still not printed.

Comment: You need to do `return graph`. Just stating `graph` at the end of the function doesn't return it in Python.